# git pull doesn't change anything

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git and Github, I understand that Git is not a place to storage files, but changes.

So I created a testing branch to do tests, and I found some bugs. So my boss tell me to create a bugfixed branch and commit all the bug fixing to it(eventually we will merge this branch to master).

Now I created a new branch called bugfixed from master in Github, now I git pull it to my local bugfixed branch, but nothing changed(in master branch there is no testing, so is the bugfixed branch), I can still see the testing in local. Why is that? Shouldn't my local file be exactly the same as the remote bugfixed branch when I git pull it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you went backwards on this (unless you're using GitHub's web UI to develop; in that case, *Godspeed*).

You want to create a *local* branch off of master called `bugfixed`.  You'd do this locally instead of on GitHub:

```
git checkout master
git pull # make sure you're up to date
git checkout -b bugfixed
```

You'd then do your work there, and you would want to publish the branch while you work on it (for review purposes at least), so you would push it to GitHub:

```
git push -u origin bugfixed # while on the bugfixed branch
```

Once you're done, you'd merge it back into `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfixed
```

Of course, if the branch already exists on the remote, then you can just check it out:

```
git checkout bugfixed
```

...but next time, seriously, don't create remote branches until you've got local changes.  It's a serious mental context switch to do it in that way.

Comment: so my question is, after git pull, my local file should be exactly the same as the remote master. But the thing is before I git pull, I create some tests on local that the remote master doesn't have, so after I git pull, shouldn't these tests be deleted?

Comment: `git pull` is only going to update the specific local branch you're on.  If you're trying to get work from another branch, you don't want to use pull - if the remote branch exists, use the form I describe above.  Otherwise, create the branch in a conventional manner with `git checkout -b`.